CSS Descendant Combinator (#divName img{}) make a bug
I want to make a simple slider. I wrote this code and found a ridiculous problem.
I have a div with 3 images:
<div id="container">
    <img src="Images/m1.png" alt="">
    <img src="Images/m2.png" alt="">
    <img src="Images/m3.png" alt="">
    <h3> Slider </h3>        
</div>    

and in style i have this :
#container img {
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;            
    mix-blend-mode: darken;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;            
}

and in script a few lines toggle fade_in class to images...
const container=document.getElementById("container");
const slides = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
let index=0;

setInterval(function(){slider()},2000)

slides[index].classList.toggle("fade_in")

function slider(){
    slides[index].classList.toggle("fade_in")
    index++;
    if(index == slides.length)
        index=0;

    slides[index].classList.toggle("fade_in");
}

It does not work. But if I change #container img{...} to img{..}, it works. Why?

when i use first method div appear without anything

May I suggest you read about CSS specificity (MDN), and then play with a specificity calculator.

If you create a runnable snippet which shows the problem we can more easily help you. Use <> in the editor.

For this kind of question - given that it's pure JS/CSS/HTML, you can create a runnable embed which makes it Much easier to help you.

You have not shown us any CSS for your fade_in class. But my guess here would be, that you have a simple specificity issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
